# Passport.js code is giving Error: authenticate must be overridden by subclass

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I have define the local strategy in *config/passport.js* file
Here is the code for strategy

```
passport.use('local', new localStrategy({
    userNameField: 'email',
    passwordFiled: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done){
    console.log("\n\n\n\nInside passport.js")
    User.findOne({'email':email}, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            return done(null, false);
        }
        if(user){
            return done(null, false, {message:"Email is already in use"});
        }

        var newUser = new User();
        newUser.email = email;
        newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
        newUser.save(function(err, result){
            if(err){
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, newUser);
        });

    });
}));
```

The strategy is used by the register route in *routes/users.js*
Here is the route

```
router.get('/register', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('user/register',{});
});

router.post('/register', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/register',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

The view for register

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">   
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <br><br><br>
        <form action="/users/register" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="EmailAddress">Email Address</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We will never share your email with anyone else</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" aria-describedby="passwordHelp" name="password" placeholder="{{{hello}}}">
                <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Sign Up </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Upon accessing the route i.e *localhost:3000/users/register*

following error is displayed

```
Error: Strategy#authenticate must be overridden by subclass
    at Strategy.authenticate (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\passport-strategy\lib\strategy.js:21:9)
    at attempt (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:361:16)
    at authenticate (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:362:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Muhammad Hassam\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

I have looked for solution, couldn't find any details related to this error.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) you should put your `passport.authenticate` in a function with `req`, `res` args.

Try this code:

```
router.post('/register', ( req, res, next ) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/register',
        failureFlash: true
    } )( req, res, next );
} );
```

Comment: I have used passport.authenticate in the function. The error has gone but it goes infinite.

Comment: Remove `next` from the first brackets and remove all `( req, res, next )` brackets at the and. Then try

Comment: I have removed the next. The error is not displayed but the server does not respond and wait for local host.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same error when i try to:

```
import {Strategy as LocalStrategy} from 'passport'
```

, 
but when i use

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy
```

or

```
const LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy
```

everything works good.

just

1):  change line  of code with `import`  to line with `const` or `var` ?

or

2): create `instance of` `LocalStrategy` (i don't try it, but maybe it work too)?